# Switch between branches gives me error

Tags: git, github

Every time i switch between branches I get error.

I've done this a couple of times:

https://help.github.com/articles/dealing-with-line-endings

```
    git rm --cached -r .
# Remove everything from the index.


git reset --hard
# Write both the index and working directory from git's database.


git add .
# Prepare to make a commit by staging all the files that will get normalized.

# This is your chance to inspect which files were never normalized. You should 
# get lots of messages like: "warning: CRLF will be replaced by LF in file."

git commit -m "Normalize line endings"
# Commit
```

And the problem still occurs.

My .gitattribute file looks like this:

```
# Set default behaviour, in case users don't have core.autocrlf set.
* text=auto

# Explicitly declare text files we want to always be normalized and converted 
# to native line endings on checkout.
*.c text
*.h text

# Declare files that will always have CRLF line endings on checkout.
*.sln text eol=crlf

# Denote all files that are truly binary and should not be modified.
*.png binary
*.jpg binary
```

I get the error:

"error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by checkout:"

Comment: Are the files it's listing as `following files` in folders? `git add .` will only add the files git is tracking in the immediate folder, not subfolders.

Comment: yes, that's corrent :o so how do I solve this?

Comment: I wanna normalize the whole project

Comment: You could either: `git add <file>`, where `<file>` is the full path to each file you're adding, or `git add -A`. If you're on a Unix-based machine, `man git-add` (or click [here](http://linux.die.net/man/1/git-add)).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by checkout:

This occurs because some files have not been committed to the repository. `git add .` only adds tracked files in the current directory. To fix this, you could:

- Add each file manually (`git add <file>`), giving the full path to the file,
- Use `git add -A`.

Here is the man-page for [`git-add`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/git-add).